# Actualizar array en campo JSON con Postgresql 10

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

No controlamos mucho postgres y necesitamos actualizar todas las filas de una columna en formato json, ejemplo de valor en la columna

```
{"12752": false, "12737": 3098, "12706": false, "12724": false, "12709": false, "12726": false, "12743": false, "12810": false, "12750": [3088, 3083], "12751": false}
```

Actualizar los valores simples es relativamente sencillo, por ejemplo sutituir 3098 por false. Este es nuestro trigger

```
DECLARE
    sqlSet text := '';
    sqlWhere text := '';
    newFields text := '';
    field RECORD;
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP='UPDATE' THEN
        newFields = NEW.fields;
    ELSIF TG_OP='DELETE' THEN
        newFields = '[]';
    END IF;

    FOR field IN 
        SELECT value::text::int AS id FROM json_array_elements(OLD.fields)
        EXCEPT ALL
        SELECT value::text::int AS id FROM json_array_elements(newFields::json)
    LOOP
        sqlSet := sqlSet || format(' || jsonb ''{"%1$s": false}''', field.id);
        sqlWhere := sqlWhere || format('AND parameters->>''%1$s''=''%2$s'' ', field.id, OLD.jim_id);
    END LOOP;
    
    EXECUTE format('UPDATE product_parameterization SET parameters = parameters::jsonb %1$s WHERE 1=1 %2$s', sqlSet, sqlWhere);
    
    IF TG_OP='UPDATE' THEN
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF TG_OP='DELETE' THEN
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
END;
```

Pero no encontramos una forma de actualizar los arrays sin afectar al resto de elementos, las condiciones serían:

1. Si es simple ponemos false
2. Si es un array quitamos el elemento del mismo
3. Si el array queda vacío lo cambiamos por un false

Comment: Se podría simplificar lo que realmente nos interesa es quitar los int elegidos de los arrays

Answer (score 0):

Con esta consulta conseguimos sacar las filas con los cambios deseados ahora falta ver como pasar de un SELECT a un UPDATE. Ej. actualizar la llave '12750' y quitar el valor 3052

```
SELECT jsonb_set(parameters::jsonb, '{12750}', to_jsonb(concat('{', string_agg(txt_vals, ','), '}')::int[] - '{3052}'::int[]))::json 
FROM product_parameterization
CROSS JOIN json_array_elements_text(parameters->'12750') txt_vals 
WHERE to_jsonb(parameters->'12750') @> '3052'
GROUP BY parameters::jsonb
```